# How to remove user profiles with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the script below. If I uncomment the line commented `#3`, I get the error

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): ""
At Z:\Scripts\Powershell\Remove-UserProfile.ps1:48 char:21
+                     $Profile.Delete()
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

regardless of whether I interrogate WMI using the format in `#1` or `#2`.  If I leave `#3` commented, and uncomment `#4`, I get the error

```
Remove-WmiObject : 
At Z:\Scripts\Powershell\Remove-UserProfile.ps1:49 char:21
+                     Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $Profile
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

regardless of the query string for `Get-WMIObject`.

Everything I can find on the web - including a couple of other SO questions - implies that either of these methods should work, but neither seems to. I have checked to see if the target profile is loaded, and it is not. Why can I not use WMI to delete user profiles? What can I do that *does* work, and doesn't involve downloading a utility from a third-party (which is not permitted by our "information security" team)?

Script:

```
function Remove-UserProfile {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Removes user profiles from computers
#>

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact="High")]

    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName,

        [Alias("UserName","sAMAccountName")]
        [String]$Identity,

        [Int]$Age,

        [Switch]$DomainOnly
    )

    BEGIN {
        $NoSystemAccounts = "SID!='S-1-5-18' AND SID!='S-1-5-19' AND SID!='S-1-5-20' " # Don't even bother with the system accounts.
        if ($DomainOnly) {
            $SIDQuery = "SID LIKE '$((Get-ADDomain).DomainSID)%' "                      # All domain account SIDs begin with the domain SID
        } elseif ($Identity.Length -ne 0) {
            $SIDQuery = "SID LIKE '$(Get-UserSID -AccountName $Identity)' "
        }
        $CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Age)
        $Query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile "
    }

    PROCESS{
        ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            Write-Verbose "Processing Computer $Computer..."
            if ($SIDQuery) {
                $Query += "WHERE " + $SIDQuery
                $FilterStr = $SIDQuery
            } else {
                $Query += "WHERE " + $NoSystemAccounts
                $FilterStr = $NoSystemAccounts
            }
            Write-Verbose "Querying WMI using '$Query' and filtering for profiles last used before $CutoffDate ..."
#1            $Profiles = Get-WMIObject -Query $Query | Where-Object { [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt $CutoffDate }
#2            $Profiles = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter $FilterStr | Where-Object { [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt $CutoffDate }
            ForEach ($Profile in $Profiles) {
                if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Profile)) {
#3                    $Profile.Delete()
#4                    Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $Profile
                }
            }
        }
    }

    END {}
}
```

Comment: This is a good example of how meaningless error messages get in the way of discovering a simple solution. As an aside: better not to use variable name `$profile`, because it clashes with PS's automatic variable of the same name.

Comment: Good catch on the variable name; I'll touch up the script accordingly before offering it for deployment to the rest of our tech support unit. And yes, this is one of those places where the error message was close to being "actively anti-helpful"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
You have to run the script as Administrator.