# Delete user profile using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am wondering how I can delete user profile by using Powershell?
I know the command of `Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile` which will give me the whole users on the computer.
I have 2 variables of `$computername` and `$username`.
So I wants to use the above command **to delete on a remote computer** (which is `$computername`) the profile of `$username`.
How I can do it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-WMIObject` can retrieve objects from remote computers with no problem, and not only does the `Win32_UserProfile` class have a (poorly documented) `delete()` method, a `Win32_UserProfile` object can be passed to `Remove-WMIObject`. This will, to all appearances, properly clean up the registry and files, and does in fact work on remote computers.

References:
[Get-Help Get-WMIObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject)
[Get-Help Remove-WMIObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/Remove-wmiobject)
Win32_UserProfile: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886409(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830632(v=vs.85).aspx
[My own question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472546/how-to-remove-user-profiles-with-powershell)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So if I wrote something like this:
`Get -WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $computer | where ($_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq '$user'} | foreach ($_.delete()}`

It will works? and If yes, it will also delete files from registry?

Comment: The registry doesn't contain files, but yes, it will delete the registry data, as well as the user profile files in C:\Users. You should not rely on the `localpath` for matching the user; instead, you should convert the user logon name to the corresponding SID, and work with that. The link to "My own question on this topic" above has some code that shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I saw your code,  but why should I use the sid code? If ill just use remove-wmiobject it will work?

Comment: The SID is guaranteed to be unique, and the system manages user profiles based on the SID rather than the logon name. It also allows you to filter the `Get-WMIObject` call directly, rather than piping the data into `Where-Object` or `ForEach-Object`, which may well be a consideration in a network environment when you are running against a remote computer - if you filter, as I did, you will only be retrieving the one profile; your way (with the pipe and `Where-Object`), you are retrieving potentially dozens or hundreds of objects over the network and then filtering.

Comment: When working with PowerShell, and especially remote management/administration, one of the most important principles is "filter left" - that is, apply filters at the earliest opportunity, so as to minimize the amount of data being fed into the pipeline for other filters.

Comment: Ok great. So after I recieved the sid of the user, what should I write to delete the user profile?

Comment: With the understanding that there is some coding that is specific to my enterprise's environment, you might wish to study the code in the question I posted. Now that I know _why_ it was failing when I posted it, I use it routinely to address certain problems we regularly encounter.

Comment: You are doing things that are potentially destructive. You need to fully understand what you are doing before writing your code; I recommend you do some serious research and study of PowerShell and WMI before continuing - I cannot know the details of your environment; if I give you an answer, it may not be appropriate for your situation.