# How can i hide or remove Local User and Group From Computer Management

Tags: powershell

Can i use Powershell to remove or hide Local User and Group from Computer Management?
I know that i can do it for Group Policies but i want to do it from Powershell for a specific user.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Similar questions have been asked and answered before. Please do some research.

Comment: What purpose does this serve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove user profiles with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472546/how-to-remove-user-profiles-with-powershell)

Comment: I try to create a automation script which it will create some administrator users but i want these uses have not access to Local User and Computers. But i want the Administrator user to have access.

Comment: Sorry no access to Local User and Groups through Computer Manager

Comment: That is pointless. Hiding the MMC does not prevent members of the local `Administrators` group from changing users local and/or groups. (This is because they are administrators, you see.) If you want to prevent someone from making changes to local users and/or groups, remove them from the local `Administrators` group.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. Note doing this by Group Policy will overwrite what you setup manualy.

I have added a small TUI (Text User Interface) option.

To explain the code better. In basic it changes the Registry Key for MMC from 0 to 1. The functions will disable or enable the MMC, but the menu system will ask you what do you want to do.

As you stated you know how to do this with GPO, but GPO actually uses a different DWORD called `Restrict_Run`. If this value is set before or after the PowerShell script will ignore the `-value 1`.

Local Users and Groups

```
(User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft Management Console\Restricted/Permitted snap-ins)
```

Restrict_Run

```
(HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MMC\{5D6179C8-17EC-11D1-9AA9-00C04FD8FE93})
```

.

```
##  Computer Management Values
##  Value = 0 (or not in registry) The policy is disabled or not configured. Users can open the MMC in Author mode.
##  Value = 1 The policy is enabled. Users cannot open the MMC in Author mode.

Function Disable_MMC_Computer_Management
{
New-ItemProperty -PropertyType "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MMC\{5D6179C8-17EC-11D1-9AA9-00C04FD8FE93}" -Value "1"
}
Function Enable_MMC_Computer_Management
{
New-ItemProperty -PropertyType "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MMC\{5D6179C8-17EC-11D1-9AA9-00C04FD8FE93}" -Value "0"
}

Function MMC_Computer_Management
{
Write-Host "`n Menu System:" -Fore Cyan
[int]$global:Menu = 0
while ( $global:Menu -lt 1 -or $global:Menu -gt 3 ){
Write-host "1. Disable MMC Computer Management" -Fore Cyan
Write-host "2. Enable MMC Computer Management" -Fore Cyan
Write-host "3. Exit" -Fore Cyan
[Int]$global:Menu = read-host "Choose an option 1 to 4" }
Switch( $global:Menu ){
1{Disable_MMC_Computer_Management}
2{Enable_MMC_Computer_Management}
3{Exit}
}
    }
    MMC_Computer_Management
```

Comment: i am new to powershell commands and i can not understand what this code do... if you choose 2, it enable mmc. after that what i have to insert to the path and to the name in order the Local User and Groups to disappear from the computer managment?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now i start to understand. If i want all these setting to be done automatically, what i have to change?i don't want the user to enter nothing.

Comment: I am thinking to run through GPO for all users to hide this option and only when the built in administrator log in, then this option to be un-hide. I can do this by log in script. But this is possible?